# Can I use two bluetooth keyboards on my desk, each connected to different computers?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm a big fan of the Microsoft Sculpt Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse. And I'd like to get another set for the second machine on my desk.

Will the two Keyboards and mice interfere with each other?

Thanks,

Roberto

Comment: They shouldn't unless you pair them to the same BT receiver which wouldn't accomplish your goal obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each Keyboard / mouse has to authenticate with the machine they are to be used on, the other machine will simply ignore them, until such time as you authenticate on that machine as well.

You can thus use two bluetooth devices on the same desk, albeit on different computers.